# Publish Artifact with <scope>test</scope>

Tags: java, api, maven, pom.xml, publish

What should I mention in pom.xml to make my dependency published with `<scope>test</scope>`?

Comment: What do you mean? A published version does not have a scope, the users of the published artifact state in which scope they want to use it.

Comment: I want to publish it the way JUnit is published here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit/4.12

Comment: I believe the website "mvnrepository.com" marks junit as "testing" category and thus the example has test scope.

Comment: I strongly recommend to take a look into the published pom file and not what mvnrepository displays to you https://search.maven.org/artifact/junit/junit/4.12/jar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This functionality of mvnrepository doesn't have any connection with Maven. Mvnrepository copied this functionality from javalibs.com where if some library is used a lot with some scope, then such scope it will be added to dependency tag:

- https://javalibs.com/artifact/junit/junit
- https://javalibs.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok
- Article about this mechanism: https://javalibs.com/news/android-scope-charts

Mvnrepository enhanced it a little bit and they are currently IMHO manually setting the scope for well known libraries.

FYI: Mvnrepository doesn't have anything to do with Maven Central / Sonatype

Disclaimer: I'm author of https://javalibs.com